# How to add running count to excel cell, which already has text in it?

Tags: excel, vba

Would anyone have advise on how to add running count to excel cells, which already have text in them, and without removing the said text.

Few screenshots will follow to clarify my issue.

I have received a ton of sheets which have a test case name as a text/string in the C column and they are missing a running count from the beginning of the cell (not sure if the "running count" is the correct term).
In the first screenshot you can see how I need them to be, as well as in the couple first rows of the second screenshot (column C). So the original text could be for example "Purchase order" and I want it to be "1. Purchase order" and the next cell would be "2. Purchase order" etc.

[Screenshot 1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poG1d.png)

[Screenshot 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQXpo.png)

I imagine there isn't an already existing function in excel which would solve my problem. I have played around with macros and VBA some years ago, but don't have any clue from on top of my head how to solve this.

Perhaps a macro that would go through each cell from the selected column one by one, cut the existing text, add a variable number to the cell and then copy the cut text back there after the variable, then add +1 to the variable before moving to the next cell?

So I somewhat understand the logic how it could be done, but don't have any memory how the syntax and the operators etc. work in VBA.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you want from the images, but you can do things like this:

If cell A1 has 942

and cell B1 has "slices of bread"

Then C1 can have the result "942 slices of bread":

```
=A1&" "&B1
```

Comment: The column C in the first image represent how I want the cell to look like and in the second image, the third column (also the same C column) represents what the cells look at the moment (they are without the number, they only have text in them).

So I have hundreds of cells in a column with a differing text in them and I need them to have a running count in the same cell.

Comment: Actually this solution was the correct one, although I added the ". " to it like this:

`=A2&". "&B2`

Comment: @ViliLeppäkangas glad it works for you, it's a method I use a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure neither if *running count* is the right term, but you can do it with a helper column and an easy formula:

[image]

```
=COUNTIF($C$2:C2;C2)&". "&C2
```

Then you can copy/paste as values and delete helper column

Comment: Thank you. I will look into that COUNTIF-function if that might solve the problem!